# Why do I get "error: invalid instruction mnemonic" when compiling FFmpeg for Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, clang, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile [FFmpeg 4.0](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/release/4.0) for Android using `clang` from the NDK (r18.1.5063045). My host architecture is Mac OS.

Here's my configure command:

```
./configure \
--target-os=android \
--arch=armv7-a \
--enable-cross-compile \
--cc=${ANDROID_NDK}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static
```

This completes successfully. So I run `make -j8` and get the following error:

```
In file included from libavfilter/vf_mestimate.c:22:
In file included from ./libavcodec/mathops.h:40:
./libavcodec/arm/mathops.h:90:26: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'itt'
    "cmp   %1, %2  \n\t"
                     ^
<inline asm>:3:2: note: instantiated into assembly here
    itt   gt      
    ^~~
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect Clang is targeting the host OS rather than arm32. Using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain) fixes that problem. I noticed that the build system was still using my host `strip` tool (which can't handle the arm binaries), so I fixed that by passing `--strip` to ffmpeg's configure script.

```
${ANDROID_NDK}/build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py \
    --arch arm --api 16 --install-dir /tmp/standalone-toolchain

./configure \
--target-os=android \
--arch=armv7-a \
--enable-cross-compile \
--cc=/tmp/standalone-toolchain/bin/clang \
--strip=/tmp/standalone-toolchain/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static 

make -j...
```

The build then failed with an error in libavdevice/v4l2.c:

```
CC  libavdevice/v4l2.o
libavdevice/v4l2.c:135:9: error: assigning to 'int (*)(int, unsigned long, ...)' from incompatible type
      '<overloaded function type>'
        SET_WRAPPERS();
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavdevice/v4l2.c:121:17: note: expanded from macro 'SET_WRAPPERS'
    s->ioctl_f  = prefix ## ioctl;      \
                ^           ~~~~~
/tmp/standalone-toolchain/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/bits/ioctl.h:56:5: note: candidate function has type mismatch at 2nd
      parameter (expected 'unsigned long' but has 'unsigned int')
int ioctl(int __fd, unsigned __request, ...) __overloadable __enable_if(1, "") __RENAME(ioctl);
    ^
/tmp/standalone-toolchain/bin/../sysroot/usr/include/bits/ioctl.h:36:5: note: candidate function has type mismatch at 2nd
      parameter (expected 'unsigned long' but has 'int')
int ioctl(int __fd, int __request, ...);
    ^
```

There's disagreement about the type of ioctl's second parameter. glibc declares it with type `unsigned long`:

```
int ioctl(int fd, unsigned long request, ...);
```

POSIX and [Bionic](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/de1353b8a413dc627dba30b5eb9a38fa717749e6/libc/include/bits/ioctl.h) (and musl) declare it with `int`:

```
int ioctl(int fildes, int request, ... /* arg */);
```

A similar problem happened with [PulseAudio and musl](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=85319), so I applied the same kind of fix to ffmpeg:

```
diff --git a/libavdevice/v4l2.c b/libavdevice/v4l2.c
index 10a0ff0dd6..1b9c6e760b 100644
--- a/libavdevice/v4l2.c
+++ b/libavdevice/v4l2.c
@@ -95,7 +95,11 @@ struct video_data {
     int (*open_f)(const char *file, int oflag, ...);
     int (*close_f)(int fd);
     int (*dup_f)(int fd);
+#ifdef __GLIBC__
     int (*ioctl_f)(int fd, unsigned long int request, ...);
+#else
+    int (*ioctl_f)(int fd, int request, ...);
+#endif
     ssize_t (*read_f)(int fd, void *buffer, size_t n);
     void *(*mmap_f)(void *start, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, int64_t offset);
     int (*munmap_f)(void *_start, size_t length);
```

Afterwards, the project built successfully.

FWIW: The project also built for arm64 using these changes:

- standalone toolchain: `--arch arm64`
- standalone toolchain: `--api 21`
- configure: `--arch=aarch64`
- configure: `--strip=/.../aarch64-linux-android-strip`

Comment: Didn't solve my issue unfortunately. I also get a warning about missing pkgconfig, any hint? Tried setting --pkg-config to toolchain/lib/pkgconfig but that's just a folder.